# Mapping NTFS and MVFS filesystem in Linux

Tags: linux, network-drive

I wanted to map a NTFS and MVFS network drive in Linux. Is it possible to do so and if it is how could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Samba to map network drives shared from a Windows server:  http://www.samba.org/.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html

I'm not sure if it will work for MVFS.